# Download file using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, download, paperclip

Firstly, this might be duplicate question but due to time limitation, i couldn't search throughly. I wish to download a file that was uploaded using paperclip. My code to download is below:

```
def download_digital
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:photo])
    send_file @photo.image.path,
              filename: @photo.image_file_name,
              type: @photo.image_content_type,
              disposition: 'attachment',
              x_sendfile: true

    puts "-----------Downloded----------"
  end
```

When this is called, i get

```
Sent file /Users/c193/Documents/***/***/***/public/assets/photos/298/original/Wedding_2.jpeg (0.1ms)
-----------Downloaded----------
```

This makes it clear that the file is obtained. However, **the file is not being actually downloaded**. I dont know what i'm missing. I'm a newbie so any guidance will be helpful .

P.S: Also **sorry for a duplicate question** (in case; time limitation and no clue what to search). Thank You in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if what is found the problem was **actually** is the problem but so far i have come to the conclusion that the use of ajax was what was creating an issue. In the console i got that the file is downloaded but it was not actually getting downloaded. I am posting a new question for the same. If anyone has an explanation for such behaviour, please post a comment regarding this. Thanx :)